# Tool to Surround or Wrap Highlighted Text

Tags: ide

StackOverflow's WYSIWYG has the ability to quickly surround highlighted text through keyboard shortcuts.

For example, when I push Ctrl+B on some highlighted text, it would bold the text or surround it with two stars.

I am looking for a tool that will give me this function but with "custom-input". That is... instead of bolding the word, I **could** surround it with a <div> tag or... in my case, I need to localize my Wordpress Plug-in, thus **__("Surrounded Text")**.

I am currently using Notepad++ but I can't find any way to create this function.

Can this be done in Notepad++?
If it can not, I would like some suggestion for a IDE that can.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've never used an "optimized" text editor, Vim would be a sea change, but it does have a great [surround.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697).

> Emphasize hello: `ysiw<em>`
>
> `<em>Hello</em> world!`
>
> Finally, let's try out visual mode.
>   Press a capital `V` (for linewise visual
>   mode) followed by `S<p
>   class="important">`.
>
> `<p class="important">
>
>        <em>Hello</em>> world!
>
>   </p>`

---

Alternatively, you could probably get a fair bit of the functionality for which you are looking with an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script, but at best I think you'd have to do the highlight-first thing like the StackOverflow WYSIWYG editor.

Still, this would probably allow you to keep using Notepad++.

Comment: AutoHotkey works very well. I think it is the same as "Autoit". The [syntax] + cut+paste + [/syntax] is instantaneous and does exactly what I want. Thanks. Maybe one day, I should stick to Vim.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in VIM using the [*surround* plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697)